# How can a set a node to scene co-ordinates [0, 0] even when the size of the scene changes [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

I want to set a TabPane `Drawer_L` (setSide(Side.Left)) to the scene coordinates of 0, 0, no matter the size of the screen

The Code I am currently using does not work

```
Master.widthProperty().addListener((o, old, width) -> {

        Drawer_L.setTranslateX(Master.localToScene(0, 0, true).getX());

    });
```

Where `Master` is a StackPane which is a direct child of the scene

Did I misunderstand the documentation? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't need (or use) a listener for this. Just do `StackPane.setAlignment(drawerL, Pos.TOP_LEFT)`.

Comment: Can I add a bias to that? say in case at some points I need it to be a bit to the left or right of 0,0  ? @James_D

Comment: Either add padding to the stack pane (which will move everything in by the specified amount) or set the insets on `drawerL`.

Comment: @James_D Alright cool, so, how do I accept your answer?

Comment: I'll add a proper answer when I'm back at the computer: interface is too difficult to answer on a phone.

Comment: Alright, no worries

Comment: java naming conventions please!